# Detect with regex if emoji is country flag

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, pcre

I've been trying to make a regex that that can detect if an emoji is a country flag or not. I want the regex to match all country flags (from  Ascension Island, to  Zimbabwe).

My approach was putting all the country flags one by one in the regex. I was hoping that someone could show me a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the regex precise you can only build regex ranges.

```js
var country_emoji_ranges = ['\\u{1F1E6}[\\u{1F1E9}-\\u{1F1EC}\\u{1F1EE}\\u{1F1F1}\\u{1F1F2}\\u{1F1F4}\\u{1F1F6}-\\u{1F1FA}\\u{1F1FC}\\u{1F1FD}\\u{1F1FF}]',
 '\\u{1F1E7}[\\u{1F1E6}\\u{1F1E7}\\u{1F1E9}-\\u{1F1EF}\\u{1F1F1}-\\u{1F1F4}\\u{1F1F6}-\\u{1F1F9}\\u{1F1FB}\\u{1F1FC}\\u{1F1FE}\\u{1F1FF}]',
 '\\u{1F1E8}[\\u{1F1E6}\\u{1F1E8}\\u{1F1E9}\\u{1F1EB}-\\u{1F1EE}\\u{1F1F0}-\\u{1F1F4}\\u{1F1F7}\\u{1F1FA}-\\u{1F1FF}]',
 '\\u{1F1E9}[\\u{1F1EA}\\u{1F1EF}\\u{1F1F0}\\u{1F1F2}\\u{1F1F4}\\u{1F1FF}]',
 '\\u{1F1EA}[\\u{1F1E8}\\u{1F1EA}\\u{1F1EC}\\u{1F1ED}\\u{1F1F7}-\\u{1F1F9}]',
 '\\u{1F1EB}[\\u{1F1EE}\\u{1F1EF}\\u{1F1F0}\\u{1F1F2}\\u{1F1F4}\\u{1F1F7}]',
 '\\u{1F1EC}[\\u{1F1E6}\\u{1F1E7}\\u{1F1E9}-\\u{1F1EE}\\u{1F1F1}-\\u{1F1F3}\\u{1F1F5}-\\u{1F1FA}\\u{1F1FC}\\u{1F1FE}]',
 '\\u{1F1ED}[\\u{1F1F0}\\u{1F1F2}\\u{1F1F3}\\u{1F1F7}\\u{1F1F9}\\u{1F1FA}]',
 '\\u{1F1EE}[\\u{1F1E9}-\\u{1F1F4}\\u{1F1F6}-\\u{1F1F9}]',
 '\\u{1F1EF}[\\u{1F1EA}\\u{1F1F2}\\u{1F1F4}\\u{1F1F5}]',
 '\\u{1F1F0}[\\u{1F1EA}\\u{1F1EC}-\\u{1F1EE}\\u{1F1F2}\\u{1F1F3}\\u{1F1F5}\\u{1F1F7}\\u{1F1FC}\\u{1F1FE}\\u{1F1FF}]',
 '\\u{1F1F1}[\\u{1F1E6}-\\u{1F1E8}\\u{1F1EE}\\u{1F1F0}\\u{1F1F8}-\\u{1F1FB}\\u{1F1FE}]',
 '\\u{1F1F2}[\\u{1F1E6}\\u{1F1E8}-\\u{1F1ED}\\u{1F1F0}-\\u{1F1FF}]',
 '\\u{1F1F3}[\\u{1F1E6}\\u{1F1E8}\\u{1F1EA}-\\u{1F1EC}\\u{1F1EE}\\u{1F1F1}\\u{1F1F4}\\u{1F1F5}\\u{1F1F7}\\u{1F1FA}\\u{1F1FF}]',
 '\\u{1F1F4}\\u{1F1F2}',
 '\\u{1F1F5}[\\u{1F1E6}\\u{1F1EA}-\\u{1F1ED}\\u{1F1F0}-\\u{1F1F3}\\u{1F1F7}-\\u{1F1F9}\\u{1F1FC}\\u{1F1FE}]',
 '\\u{1F1F6}\\u{1F1E6}',
 '\\u{1F1F7}[\\u{1F1EA}\\u{1F1F4}\\u{1F1F8}\\u{1F1FA}\\u{1F1FC}]',
 '\\u{1F1F8}[\\u{1F1E6}-\\u{1F1EA}\\u{1F1EC}-\\u{1F1F4}\\u{1F1F7}-\\u{1F1F9}\\u{1F1FB}\\u{1F1FD}-\\u{1F1FF}]',
 '\\u{1F1F9}[\\u{1F1E8}\\u{1F1E9}\\u{1F1EB}-\\u{1F1ED}\\u{1F1EF}-\\u{1F1F4}\\u{1F1F7}\\u{1F1F9}\\u{1F1FB}\\u{1F1FC}\\u{1F1FF}]',
 '\\u{1F1FA}[\\u{1F1E6}\\u{1F1EC}\\u{1F1F2}\\u{1F1F8}\\u{1F1FE}\\u{1F1FF}]',
 '\\u{1F1FB}[\\u{1F1E6}\\u{1F1E8}\\u{1F1EA}\\u{1F1EC}\\u{1F1EE}\\u{1F1F3}\\u{1F1FA}]',
 '\\u{1F1FC}[\\u{1F1EB}\\u{1F1F8}]',
 '\\u{1F1FE}[\\u{1F1EA}\\u{1F1F9}]',
 '\\u{1F1FF}[\\u{1F1E6}\\u{1F1F2}\\u{1F1FC}]'
];
var country_emoji_rx = new RegExp(country_emoji_ranges.join('|'), 'ug');
var text = "\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1E9}, \u{1F1E6}\u{1F1EA}, \u{1F1E6}\u{1F1EB}, \u{1F1E6}\u{1F1EC}, \u{1F1E6}\u{1F1EE}, \u{1F1E6}\u{1F1F1}, \u{1F1E6}\u{1F1F2}, \u{1F1E6}\u{1F1F4}, \u{1F1E6}\u{1F1F6}, \u{1F1E6}\u{1F1F7}, \u{1F1E6}\u{1F1F8}, \u{1F1E6}\u{1F1F9}, \u{1F1E6}\u{1F1FA}, \u{1F1E6}\u{1F1FC}, \u{1F1E6}\u{1F1FD}, \u{1F1E6}\u{1F1FF}, \u{1F1E7}\u{1F1E6}, \u{1F1E7}\u{1F1E7}, \u{1F1E7}\u{1F1E9}, \u{1F1E7}\u{1F1EA}, \u{1F1E7}\u{1F1EB}, \u{1F1E7}\u{1F1EC}, \u{1F1E7}\u{1F1ED}, \u{1F1E7}\u{1F1EE}, \u{1F1E7}\u{1F1EF}, \u{1F1E7}\u{1F1F1}, \u{1F1E7}\u{1F1F2}, \u{1F1E7}\u{1F1F3}, \u{1F1E7}\u{1F1F4}, \u{1F1E7}\u{1F1F6}, \u{1F1E7}\u{1F1F7}, \u{1F1E7}\u{1F1F8}, \u{1F1E7}\u{1F1F9}, \u{1F1E7}\u{1F1FB}, \u{1F1E7}\u{1F1FC}, \u{1F1E7}\u{1F1FE}, \u{1F1E7}\u{1F1FF}, \u{1F1E8}\u{1F1E6}, \u{1F1E8}\u{1F1E8}, \u{1F1E8}\u{1F1E9}, \u{1F1E8}\u{1F1EB}, \u{1F1E8}\u{1F1EC}, \u{1F1E8}\u{1F1ED}, \u{1F1E8}\u{1F1EE}, \u{1F1E8}\u{1F1F0}, \u{1F1E8}\u{1F1F1}, \u{1F1E8}\u{1F1F2}, \u{1F1E8}\u{1F1F3}, \u{1F1E8}\u{1F1F4}, \u{1F1E8}\u{1F1F7}, \u{1F1E8}\u{1F1FA}, \u{1F1E8}\u{1F1FB}, \u{1F1E8}\u{1F1FC}, \u{1F1E8}\u{1F1FD}, \u{1F1E8}\u{1F1FE}, \u{1F1E8}\u{1F1FF}, \u{1F1E9}\u{1F1EA}, \u{1F1E9}\u{1F1EF}, \u{1F1E9}\u{1F1F0}, \u{1F1E9}\u{1F1F2}, \u{1F1E9}\u{1F1F4}, \u{1F1E9}\u{1F1FF}, \u{1F1EA}\u{1F1E8}, \u{1F1EA}\u{1F1EA}, \u{1F1EA}\u{1F1EC}, \u{1F1EA}\u{1F1ED}, \u{1F1EA}\u{1F1F7}, \u{1F1EA}\u{1F1F8}, \u{1F1EA}\u{1F1F9}, \u{1F1EB}\u{1F1EE}, \u{1F1EB}\u{1F1EF}, \u{1F1EB}\u{1F1F0}, \u{1F1EB}\u{1F1F2}, \u{1F1EB}\u{1F1F4}, \u{1F1EB}\u{1F1F7}, \u{1F1EC}\u{1F1E6}, \u{1F1EC}\u{1F1E7}, \u{1F1EC}\u{1F1E9}, \u{1F1EC}\u{1F1EA}, \u{1F1EC}\u{1F1EB}, \u{1F1EC}\u{1F1EC}, \u{1F1EC}\u{1F1ED}, \u{1F1EC}\u{1F1EE}, \u{1F1EC}\u{1F1F1}, \u{1F1EC}\u{1F1F2}, \u{1F1EC}\u{1F1F3}, \u{1F1EC}\u{1F1F5}, \u{1F1EC}\u{1F1F6}, \u{1F1EC}\u{1F1F7}, \u{1F1EC}\u{1F1F8}, \u{1F1EC}\u{1F1F9}, \u{1F1EC}\u{1F1FA}, \u{1F1EC}\u{1F1FC}, \u{1F1EC}\u{1F1FE}, \u{1F1ED}\u{1F1F0}, \u{1F1ED}\u{1F1F2}, \u{1F1ED}\u{1F1F3}, \u{1F1ED}\u{1F1F7}, \u{1F1ED}\u{1F1F9}, \u{1F1ED}\u{1F1FA}, \u{1F1EE}\u{1F1E9}, \u{1F1EE}\u{1F1EA}, \u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F1}, \u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F2}, \u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F3}, \u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F4}, \u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F6}, \u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F7}, \u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F8}, \u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F9}, \u{1F1EF}\u{1F1EA}, \u{1F1EF}\u{1F1F2}, \u{1F1EF}\u{1F1F4}, \u{1F1EF}\u{1F1F5}, \u{1F1F0}\u{1F1EA}, \u{1F1F0}\u{1F1EC}, \u{1F1F0}\u{1F1ED}, \u{1F1F0}\u{1F1EE}, \u{1F1F0}\u{1F1F2}, \u{1F1F0}\u{1F1F3}, \u{1F1F0}\u{1F1F5}, \u{1F1F0}\u{1F1F7}, \u{1F1F0}\u{1F1FC}, \u{1F1F0}\u{1F1FE}, \u{1F1F0}\u{1F1FF}, \u{1F1F1}\u{1F1E6}, \u{1F1F1}\u{1F1E7}, \u{1F1F1}\u{1F1E8}, \u{1F1F1}\u{1F1EE}, \u{1F1F1}\u{1F1F0}, \u{1F1F1}\u{1F1F7}, \u{1F1F1}\u{1F1F8}, \u{1F1F1}\u{1F1F9}, \u{1F1F1}\u{1F1FA}, \u{1F1F1}\u{1F1FB}, \u{1F1F1}\u{1F1FE}, \u{1F1F2}\u{1F1E6}, \u{1F1F2}\u{1F1E8}, \u{1F1F2}\u{1F1E9}, \u{1F1F2}\u{1F1EA}, \u{1F1F2}\u{1F1EB}, \u{1F1F2}\u{1F1EC}, \u{1F1F2}\u{1F1ED}, \u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F0}, \u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F1}, \u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F2}, \u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F3}, \u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F4}, \u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F5}, \u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F6}, \u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F7}, \u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F8}, \u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F9}, \u{1F1F2}\u{1F1FA}, \u{1F1F2}\u{1F1FB}, \u{1F1F2}\u{1F1FC}, \u{1F1F2}\u{1F1FD}, \u{1F1F2}\u{1F1FE}, \u{1F1F2}\u{1F1FF}, \u{1F1F3}\u{1F1E6}, \u{1F1F3}\u{1F1E8}, \u{1F1F3}\u{1F1EA}, \u{1F1F3}\u{1F1EB}, \u{1F1F3}\u{1F1EC}, \u{1F1F3}\u{1F1EE}, \u{1F1F3}\u{1F1F1}, \u{1F1F3}\u{1F1F4}, \u{1F1F3}\u{1F1F5}, \u{1F1F3}\u{1F1F7}, \u{1F1F3}\u{1F1FA}, \u{1F1F3}\u{1F1FF}, \u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F2}, \u{1F1F5}\u{1F1E6}, \u{1F1F5}\u{1F1EA}, \u{1F1F5}\u{1F1EB}, \u{1F1F5}\u{1F1EC}, \u{1F1F5}\u{1F1ED}, \u{1F1F5}\u{1F1F0}, \u{1F1F5}\u{1F1F1}, \u{1F1F5}\u{1F1F2}, \u{1F1F5}\u{1F1F3}, \u{1F1F5}\u{1F1F7}, \u{1F1F5}\u{1F1F8}, \u{1F1F5}\u{1F1F9}, \u{1F1F5}\u{1F1FC}, \u{1F1F5}\u{1F1FE}, \u{1F1F6}\u{1F1E6}, \u{1F1F7}\u{1F1EA}, \u{1F1F7}\u{1F1F4}, \u{1F1F7}\u{1F1F8}, \u{1F1F7}\u{1F1FA}, \u{1F1F7}\u{1F1FC}, \u{1F1F8}\u{1F1E6}, \u{1F1F8}\u{1F1E7}, \u{1F1F8}\u{1F1E8}, \u{1F1F8}\u{1F1E9}, \u{1F1F8}\u{1F1EA}, \u{1F1F8}\u{1F1EC}, \u{1F1F8}\u{1F1ED}, \u{1F1F8}\u{1F1EE}, \u{1F1F8}\u{1F1EF}, \u{1F1F8}\u{1F1F0}, \u{1F1F8}\u{1F1F1}, \u{1F1F8}\u{1F1F2}, \u{1F1F8}\u{1F1F3}, \u{1F1F8}\u{1F1F4}, \u{1F1F8}\u{1F1F7}, \u{1F1F8}\u{1F1F8}, \u{1F1F8}\u{1F1F9}, \u{1F1F8}\u{1F1FB}, \u{1F1F8}\u{1F1FD}, \u{1F1F8}\u{1F1FE}, \u{1F1F8}\u{1F1FF}, \u{1F1F9}\u{1F1E8}, \u{1F1F9}\u{1F1E9}, \u{1F1F9}\u{1F1EB}, \u{1F1F9}\u{1F1EC}, \u{1F1F9}\u{1F1ED}, \u{1F1F9}\u{1F1EF}, \u{1F1F9}\u{1F1F0}, \u{1F1F9}\u{1F1F1}, \u{1F1F9}\u{1F1F2}, \u{1F1F9}\u{1F1F3}, \u{1F1F9}\u{1F1F4}, \u{1F1F9}\u{1F1F7}, \u{1F1F9}\u{1F1F9}, \u{1F1F9}\u{1F1FB}, \u{1F1F9}\u{1F1FC}, \u{1F1F9}\u{1F1FF}, \u{1F1FA}\u{1F1E6}, \u{1F1FA}\u{1F1EC}, \u{1F1FA}\u{1F1F2}, \u{1F1FA}\u{1F1F8}, \u{1F1FA}\u{1F1FE}, \u{1F1FA}\u{1F1FF}, \u{1F1FB}\u{1F1E6}, \u{1F1FB}\u{1F1E8}, \u{1F1FB}\u{1F1EA}, \u{1F1FB}\u{1F1EC}, \u{1F1FB}\u{1F1EE}, \u{1F1FB}\u{1F1F3}, \u{1F1FB}\u{1F1FA}, \u{1F1FC}\u{1F1EB}, \u{1F1FC}\u{1F1F8}, \u{1F1FE}\u{1F1EA}, \u{1F1FE}\u{1F1F9}, \u{1F1FF}\u{1F1E6}, \u{1F1FF}\u{1F1F2}, \u{1F1FF}\u{1F1FC}";
console.log(text.match(country_emoji_rx).length);
```

In case you want to match those in JS environments that do not support `u` flag you may use a [transpiled](https://mothereff.in/regexpu) version:

```
/(?:\uD83C\uDDE6)(?:\uD83C[\uDDE9-\uDDEC\uDDEE\uDDF1\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDF6-\uDDFA\uDDFC\uDDFD\uDDFF])|(?:\uD83C\uDDE7)(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE7\uDDE9-\uDDEF\uDDF1-\uDDF4\uDDF6-\uDDF9\uDDFB\uDDFC\uDDFE\uDDFF])|(?:\uD83C\uDDE8)(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDE9\uDDEB-\uDDEE\uDDF0-\uDDF4\uDDF7\uDDFA-\uDDFF])|(?:\uD83C\uDDE9)(?:\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDEF\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDFF])|(?:\uD83C\uDDEA)(?:\uD83C[\uDDE8\uDDEA\uDDEC\uDDED\uDDF7-\uDDF9])|(?:\uD83C\uDDEB)(?:\uD83C[\uDDEE-\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDF7])|(?:\uD83C\uDDEC)(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE7\uDDE9-\uDDEE\uDDF1-\uDDF3\uDDF5-\uDDFA\uDDFC\uDDFE])|(?:\uD83C\uDDED)(?:\uD83C[\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDF3\uDDF7\uDDF9\uDDFA])|(?:\uD83C\uDDEE)(?:\uD83C[\uDDE9-\uDDF4\uDDF6-\uDDF9])|(?:\uD83C\uDDEF)(?:\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDF5])|(?:\uD83C\uDDF0)(?:\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDEC-\uDDEE\uDDF2\uDDF3\uDDF5\uDDF7\uDDFC\uDDFE\uDDFF])|(?:\uD83C\uDDF1)(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6-\uDDE8\uDDEE\uDDF0\uDDF8-\uDDFB\uDDFE])|(?:\uD83C\uDDF2)(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8-\uDDED\uDDF0-\uDDFF])|(?:\uD83C\uDDF3)(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDEA-\uDDEC\uDDEE\uDDF1\uDDF4\uDDF5\uDDF7\uDDFA\uDDFF])|(?:\uD83C\uDDF4)(?:\uD83C\uDDF2)|(?:\uD83C\uDDF5)(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDEA-\uDDED\uDDF0-\uDDF3\uDDF7-\uDDF9\uDDFC\uDDFE])|(?:\uD83C\uDDF6)(?:\uD83C\uDDE6)|(?:\uD83C\uDDF7)(?:\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDF4\uDDF8\uDDFA\uDDFC])|(?:\uD83C\uDDF8)(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6-\uDDEA\uDDEC-\uDDF4\uDDF7-\uDDF9\uDDFB\uDDFD-\uDDFF])|(?:\uD83C\uDDF9)(?:\uD83C[\uDDE8\uDDE9\uDDEB-\uDDED\uDDEF-\uDDF4\uDDF7\uDDF9\uDDFB\uDDFC\uDDFF])|(?:\uD83C\uDDFA)(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDEC\uDDF2\uDDF8\uDDFE\uDDFF])|(?:\uD83C\uDDFB)(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDEA\uDDEC\uDDEE\uDDF3\uDDFA])|(?:\uD83C\uDDFC)(?:\uD83C[\uDDEB\uDDF8])|(?:\uD83C\uDDFE)(?:\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDF9])|(?:\uD83C\uDDFF)(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDF2\uDDFC])/g
```

Answer (score 5):

A country flag emoji corresponds to a pair of native symbols (two letters) that identify the country (eg. FR for France - [see list](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/iso3166)).
What you can do is use a regex that match any combination of these letters. Of course, this will include non-existent country codes (eg. ZZ), but this should exclude any other emoji.

So here it is:

```
var reg = /[\uD83C][\uDDE6-\uDDFF][\uD83C][\uDDE6-\uDDFF]/;
reg.test(""); // false
reg.test(""); // true
```

Comment: `reg.test("")` returns `false`. Also `reg.test("")`

Answer (score 4):

Since the flags are essentially created from two Unicode characters, a possible option would be `str.match(/[-]{2}/u)`, assuming that `str` contains the string. The two values in the range expression are U+1F1E6 (Regional Indicator Symbol Letter A) and U+1F1FF (Regional Indicator Symbol Letter Z), both available since Unicode 6.0.

The major drawback of this solution is the fact it matches all possible combinations of those indicator symbols and thus does not guarantee the indicator to represent a valid contry, eg.  would be matched as well as .

Answer (score -1):

```js
const regex = /^((?![\p{Regional_Indicator}]).)*$/u;
regex.test("country_flag_emoji"); // false
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Please add some explanation of your code.